# Django CRUD admin view: return error message

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using the CRUD admin view to edit some text.
I override the `save()` method of my model to run some validation before. that is, if the input string is not a well-formed xml, it doesn't save it. I'd like to notify the user.
However, I can only find solutions that need the request object and the messages framework but, as far as I'm concerned, I can not access `request` from  `save()`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
        doc = parseString(self.content)
        super(Screen, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception, e:
        from django.contrib import messages
        # messages.error(request, "This is a bad bad message")
        print("this is a bad bad string")
        return
```

How can I send an error message?
After hitting "save" the user is redirected again to the list of instances of that  model. is there a way to redirect it to the form? are these problems related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @FernandoFreitasAlves I could write a solution.
I realised that my model can also be loaded from a file and then stored in the DB, without the CRUD admin page, so I also overide the `save()` method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    xml = "<screen>" + self.content + "</screen>"
    parseString(xml.encode("utf-8"))
    super(Screen, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def clean(self):
    try:
        from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
        doc = parseString(self.content)
    except Exception, e:
        from django import forms
        raise forms.ValidationError("It's not a XML")
    super(Screen,self).clean()
```

I think I don't want to overide the `full_clean()` method. I can't see a reason for that. The docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) say

> This method calls Model.clean_fields(), Model.clean(), and
>   Model.validate_unique(), in that order and raises a ValidationError
>   that has a message_dict attribute containing errors from all three
>   stages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use the clean method inside your models, in that way you will validate your data in the admin, just like the other admin fields

Inside your `Model`:

```
def clean(self):
   try:
        from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
        doc = parseString(self.content)

    except Exception, e:
        from django import forms
        raise forms.ValidationError(u"It's not a XML")

    super(YourModel,self).clean()

def full_clean(self, exclude=None):
    return self.clean()
```

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields

Comment: I just tried to override save_model in a ScreenAdmin class. I got the error,but because it isn't a validation error, it also shows the successful message. I'll try your solution too. thanks!